# How to set HTML5 events on a widget?

Tags: javascript, html, dojo

Working with [this example from W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp)  I want to drag one widget onto another widget (they are sibling widgets)

I add the draggable attribute to my element that I want to drag like this

```
<div draggable="true" id="textbox" >
```

But on the receiving widget how do I define the function allowDrop inside a template based widget?  Also how can i determine which widget is being dragged?

HTML for Widget I want to drop onto

```
<div ondragover="allowDrop(event)"   >
    <div id="canvas"   class="grid container">
        <div   style="color:red"  data-dojo-attach-point="canvasNode"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And in my widget javascript I defined allowDrop like this

```
return declare([_WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin], {

    templateString: template,

    allowDrop: function (ev) {
        alert("test");
        ev.preventDefault();
    },
    ....
  }
```

The error I get when the mouse enters the widget region, and tries to fire the allowDrop event is the following

> Uncaught ReferenceError: allowDrop is not defined

**EDIT**

Everything works fine if I include the functions inside the script tags of index.html like this

```
<script>
    function allowDrop(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
    }

    function drag(ev) {
        ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
    }

    function drop(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
        //ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the event attribute from the HTML and instead use dojo/on in startup or postcreate to programmatically attach the event like this

```
    startup: function () {
        this.inherited(arguments);

        var that = this;

        on(dom.byId("canvas"), "dragover", function (event) {
            that.allowDrop(event);

        });

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `data-dojo-attach-event` to bind the event and call the function that is in the scope of the widget.

```
<div data-dojo-attach-event= "ondragover:allowDrop(event)">
    <div id="canvas"   class="grid container">
        <div style="color:red"  data-dojo-attach-point="canvasNode"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Try camel casing with the name of the event if this does not work.